# Combined perspective and orthogonal rendering

Tags: three.js

I have a question regarding drawing objects in screen space. My issue is that I want to draw both in perspective and in screen space (orthogonal). I have tried using to cameras and two scenes. But when I render the second scene using the renderer the first scene i cleared.

Is there a way to do this without using two separate renderers?

The reason I want to do this is that I want to overlay selection graphics and other objects in screen space on top of the perspective render.

Comment: Did you try one renderer, 2 scenes, 2 cameras and `renderer.autoClear = false;`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved using one renderer, 2 scenes, 2 cameras and renderer.autoClear = false.